# Why don't my controllers work in the VR game that I'm making?

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, oculus

I am currently starting with the development of a vr game in Unity. Now i've followed multiple tutorials on how to make hands by using the controllers. (I am using the Quest 2) I can't get it to work, does anybody know why?
(My controllers do work in normal games and everything)

Comment: "I've followed multiple tutorials" doesn't tell us anything about the code you're using, now what the issue might be. Can you provide a minimal set of steps you've tried?